# How do I get the location of a box within an image in Flutter?

Tags: opencv, flutter, image-processing, firebase-mlkit, tensorflow-lite

I am writing a Flutter app to solve a Sudoku based on an picture taken with the camera.  Here is the source code: https://github.com/lachiejames/SudokuSolver

So far, I can do this if the Sudoku is in a precise location within the camera.  **However if it is not in this precise location, it will not work**.

I would like to improve this by using some kind of image-processing technique to detect the location of the Sudoku within the image.  But as of yet, I have not found a viable way to do this in Flutter.

Comment: I beg you to shorten your question. Just to tell about the part you want to solve.

Comment: Done.  I removed the parts where I explain my current method for solving it, and the potential solutions I have tried.

Comment: This is a pretty hard problem. You would enforce users to put the camera to the right angle. You can put a rectangle on the screen and make sure corners are matching.

Comment: As mentioned in my pre-edited post, that is what I am currently doing.  But I would like to find something that doesn't depend on the position being so precise.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no package for that directly. You might train some models and use them with current ML libraries to locate the box. This is more of an image processing problem here. You might try to search native Android/iOS implementatios for this. You can then wrap them and use them in a Flutter app.

Comment: I also suggest you to bring this up to some AI community (Discord channel etc.) to get some advices there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I am not currently in any discords/slacks.  Is there one in particular you would recommend for this problem?

Comment: Never been in one related to AI.